# Add action listener to Project Explorer in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I'm developing a plug-in for Eclipse Luna and I need to update some list of files depending on which project is selected. How would I add some kind of listener which will be activated every time user selects project in Project Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ISelectionService` to listen to selection events.

In a view or editor you can get the service with:

```java
ISelectionService service = (ISelectionService)getSite().getService(ISelectionService.class);
```

Add a listener for selection events with:

```java
service.addSelectionListener(listener);
```

or for events from a particular part:

```java
service.addSelectionListener("part id", listener);
```